# Collapsible side options with unique nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I am trying to get a collapsible product category section in my web app (based on AngularJS).

My JSON array looks like:

```
[
  {
    "Categoryid": "M60001",
    "productPrimaryCategory": "Living Room",
    "productClass":"Furniture",
    "productSubCategory":"Sofa & Sectionals",
    "productType":"Single Seater",
    "Active":"Yes"
  },
 {
    "Categoryid": "M60002",
    "productPrimaryCategory": "Living Room",
    "productClass":"Furniture",
    "productSubCategory":"Sofa & Sectionals",
    "productType":"2 Seater",
    "Active":"Yes"
  },
   {
    "Categoryid": "M60003",
    "productPrimaryCategory": "Living Room",
    "productClass":"Furniture",
    "productSubCategory":"Sofa & Sectionals",
    "productType":"3 Seater",
    "Active":"Yes"
  }..
]
```

I am trying to club all the primary categories in the JSON together as one node with multiple children (ensuring that there is only one primary category node per type.. One node per type).

**I wished to check whether there is any AngularJS or jQuery plugin to achieve something similar, as I believe what I am looking for is not unique but a common thing.**

Currently I have not started to code this part, as I am looking for an existing solution, but will share a JSFiddle with some code soon.

I checked AngularJS-ui-tree, but could not find any example similar to mine.

Here is how I expect the result:
[image]

Comment: what is the resulted json from the sample json above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to locate a drop-in solution. So I created something of my own. Here is a link to the content:

[Chaining directive within directive in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828858/chaining-directive-within-directive-in-angularjs)

Though the jsfiddle is still incomplete.. but there is a good start.. I will complete it once I have some time..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [UI BOOTSTRAP](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) or do it manually with ngShow/ngHide and adding some 'visible' property to the elements of your array

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/).

In this sample, I used the Dropdown.

```
<div class="dropdown">
```

You can repeat this element as many times you have elements in your json with `ng-repeat`

And use the properties of these elements in the dropdown items.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fr3mtbx9/)

Of course, it's just an idea.

Comment: Sorry but what you shared was not what I was looking for. I added an image of what I am expecting as a resultant.