# Chaining directive within directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wished to create something like the following using custom directive. I am able to get the "Categories" section, but not the "breadcrumb" part.

[image]

Using ng-repeat in the **breadcrumb** directive, does not work.

I can observe the **ul** of the breadcrumb but the **li** element are not appended to the **ul**.

Following is my fiddle and for some reason the code works on my side does not work on jsfiddle. But I have placed it just to give some idea.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anjhawar/yumr5z1h/4/)

```
<div ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
   <tree src="categories"></tree>
</div>
```

Tree directive calls branch on click.
Branch on click calls "breadcrumb"

ng-repeat does not work here:

```
template: '<ul><breadcrumbnode ng-repeat="node in breadcrumbs" src="node"></breadcrumbnode></ul>'
```

this is never called:

```
template: '<li><a>{{ node }}</a></li>',
```

Expectation: On click of the branch node "Mattresses" (for example in fiddle), I expect to know observe a list under div with class "bread-crumb-filter".

Any pointers on what could be the possible cause of the directive not working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For Fiddle, click JavaScript button and select AngularJS framework and Load Type - "no wrap - in body", should work.

Comment: Your Fiddle has errors with Dependency Injection.  Adding `ng-strict-di` and using angular.js instead of angular.min.js, the following error appears:  `Error: [$injector:strictdi] function($compile) is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode`.  This is an indication that you are using `$compile` somewhere that angular thinks it is not injected properly, which would break when minified.  You should probably start there.

Comment: @SlavaN. : Thanks for the tip about the fiddle, still fiddle is not neat but I guess explains the problem.

Comment: Logic of approach doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third directive is not required in jsfiddle. I hooked a service on "click" event of the "branch" node and then linked the category content to the rootscope (which was my requirement). I will see in case I can tweak the fiddle with a working implementation once I get some time.